# Formatting issue when printing

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following Class created:

---

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, id, email):
        self.__name = name
        self.__id = id
        self.__email_id = email
        self.__marks = []

#accessors
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_email(self):
        return self.__email_id

    def get_id(self):
        return self.__id

    def get_marks(self):
        return self.__marks

#mututators
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_id(self, id):
        self.__id = id

    def set_email(self, email):
        self.__email_id = email

    def set__marks(self, marks):
        self.__marks = marks

#formatted string representation of the student
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s: %s, %s, marks: %s" % (self.__id, self.__name, self.__email_id, self.__marks)

#appends the marks to the end of the marks list
    def append_marks(self, marks):
        self.__marks.append(marks)
```

---

When I call this class in the following function:

---

```
def read_classlist():
        #This function reads the classlist from file.
        global studentslist
        studentslist = []
        try:
                file=input("Enter name of the classlist file: ")
                with open(file) as f:
                        for line in f:
                                data=line.split(",")
                                s=Student(data[0],data[1],data[2])
                                studentslist.append(s)
                print("Completed reading of file %s" % file)
                for student in studentslist:
                        print(student)
                display_separator()
                menu()
                return
        except IOError:
                print("File %s could not be opened" % file)
                display_separator()
                menu()
                return
```

---

It's not printing the text properly. For some reason, it messes up the formatting for everything but the last student.

---

Example:

```
Enter name of the classlist file: classlist.txt
Completed reading of file classlist.txt
N00000001: John, john@amail.com
, marks: []
N00000002: Kelly, kelly@bmail.com
, marks: []
N00000003: Nicky, nicky@cmail.com
, marks: []
N00000004: Sam, sam@dmail.com
, marks: []
N00000005: Adam, adam@amail.com, marks: []
```

---

I can't figure out why it's creating a new line after the email. It's doing that for every data file, but the last student being displayed will always be correct.

I don't quite understand it.

Any help would be great!

Comment: maybe you could change this line `data=line.split(",")` to `data=line.rstrip().split(",")` This'll delete the return to a new line character `\n` from your data

Comment: OMG! you are a Godsend! THANK YOU!

Comment: If you want i can write it as an answer and you can accept it if it fills your needs :-)

Comment: of course! that worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change this line

`data=line.split(",")`

to

`data=line.rstrip().split(",")`

This'll delete the return to a new line character `\n` from your data and you'll have your desired output.